# Some of my iOS 10 apps are losing saved settings and information

Tags: ios, applications, preferences

Over the past week, may of my apps have started resetting, losing saved settings and information. I have an iPhone 6 on iOS 10.1.1 and a Watch on watchOS 3.1. I updated my iPhone to 10.1.1 on October 31, almost 2 weeks ago. I suspect that the NSUserDefaults of my apps are getting reset based on the data being lost:

- The Messages app showed me the "What's new in Messages" page, but my messages were not deleted.
- My theme preferences on the app Reeder were lost, but I wasn't logged out of my accounts.
- I am logged out of Facebook daily.
- I was logged out of WhatsApp once, but my messages weren't deleted, and I don't backup my messages to the cloud.
- I was logged out of all my Slack accounts.
- I may have been logged out of Strava once.

Other apps like Tweetbot and Snapchat have been functioning just fine. I'm not sure if any of this is related to updating to iOS 10.1.1. Restarting my phone has had no effect. These resets don't seem to be happening all at once. The resets don't render my phone unusable, but it's definitely annoying.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well, but unfortunately no one seems to have an answer. I had to stop using Outlook on mobile, it's just too many settings to re-set up every time, and it's clearly not even that app's fault. Another earlier thread with no help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239104/various-ios-apps-log-out-randomly-lose-all-data-settings

Comment: I would be sure your iCloud login is actually active. That means logging out and back into iCloud - Tap the name listed at the top when you open Settings, scroll to the bottom and sign out, then sign back in. When you log out, be sure and save local copy of anything prompted, and when you log back in, just merge everything. Then [restore from backup](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204184) if you have a backup. If not, make a backup with iTunes or to iCloud, then restore.